# Dell Inspiron N5110 Keyboard & Touchpad

Tags: 12.04, drivers, keyboard, touchpad, dell

> I have Dell Laptop " N 5110 "

1. How do make 2 finger scrolling work + 2 fingers zoom in & zoom out work
2. How to Fn + f3 To lock touchpad
3. How to configure **1 2 3** as shown in pic

   **3.1** For Ubuntu Software Center

   **3.2** For System Settings

   **3.3** For Screen Off

[image]

[How can I configure the touchpad and keyboard settings on a Dell Inspiron 5110?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111039/how-can-i-configure-the-touchpad-and-keyboard-settings-on-a-dell-inspiron-5110) **Nothing Work** & i did google but find nothing

```
 xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                             id=2 [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Generic Mouse                        id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                          id=3   [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_HD               id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Dell WMI hotkeys                          id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: Did the answer posted help you with the touchpad problem??

Comment: yes  > os.system("xinput --set-prop 'PS/2 Generic Mouse' 'Device Enabled' $(if [ $(expr `xinput --list-props 'PS/2 Generic Mouse' | grep 'Device Enabled' | cut -f2 -d :`) -eq 0 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi)")  > check the 2nd answer as well

Comment: Did you manage to make the scroll work on your touchpad? As I see the script only makes the touchpad stop.

Comment: Consider this answer here: http://askubuntu.com/a/199587/44254

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### 1. How do make 2 finger scrolling work + 2 fingers zoom in & zoom out work

there is an application called `Touchegg` but it is having issues with `12.04` and need to be fixed. So at this time, it won't do the job you want.

[Touchegg](http://code.google.com/p/touchegg/) is designed to bring multi-touch (touchpad) functionality to Linux based operating systems. In layman’s term, it is an open source multi-touch gesture recognizer for GNU/Linux which is backed by C++, Qt and uTouch-geis library. With TouchEgg, you can define what type of actions are to be initiated for a specific multi-touch gesture.

for more info have a [look at my answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/143952/are-there-other-gestures-for-the-synaptics-touchpad-besides-two-finger-scrolling/143956#143956). I have guided through whole process.

#### 2. How to Fn + f3 To lock touchpad?

Use application named `AutoKey`.

You can bind any key to any script or abbreviation.

> AutoKey is a desktop automation utility for Linux and X11. It allows
>   you to manage collection of scripts and phrases, and assign
>   abbreviations and hotkeys to these. This allows you to execute a
>   script or insert text on demand in whatever program you are using.

#### Latest version is v0.90.

- Where to get this? it is in the ubuntu's repository!

Open software center > search for `autokey` > install AutoKey(GTK)

- How to use this?

Open AutoKey.

#### Step 1 :

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> or from `File > Create.. > New Script`. Rename with whatever you like.

[image]

paste below code as shown,

```
import os
os.system("synclient TouchpadOff=$(if [ $(expr `synclient -l | grep TouchpadOff | cut -f2 -d =`) -eq 0 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi)")
```

[image]

Then in bottom-right corner there is three `Set` buttons to set for `Abbreviation` or `Hotkey` or `Window Filter`. Click second `Set` button (because we want to set hotkey).

[image]

Click `Press to Set` and hit a key you want to assign(in your case <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f3</kbd>. I'm hitting <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>).

Click `OK`.

Click `Save` in bottom-right corner.

Now you will see your hotkey in left panel in `HotKey` column (in my case there is *weird* key like `I` because I have assigned <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f1</kbd>).

[image]

you have set hotkey for touchpad to enable/disable ( I have coded to make it toggle rather than just use to lock it. Perhaps you'd like it :-)  ).

**3.1 For Ubuntu Software Center**

==> Go to `Step 1` described above.

just use this code when you paste.

```
import os
os.system("/usr/bin/software-center %u")
```

and set hotkey for `1` you have shown in screenshot.

thats it you have bound `1` for `Software Center`.

**3.2 For System Settings**

==> Go to `Step 1` described above.

just use this code when you paste.

```
import os
os.system("gnome-control-center")
```

and set hotkey for `2` you have shown in screenshot.

thats it you have bound `2` for `System Settings`.

**3.3 For Screen Off**

==> Go to `Step 1` described above.

just use this code when you paste.

```
import os
os.system("xset dpms force off")
```

and set hotkey for `3` you have shown in screenshot.

thats it you have bound `3` for `Monitor off`.

Comment: Does this make the scroll to work on alps touchpads, or it is just an option to turn off the touchpad?

Comment: it turns off and on touchpad (like toggle keys).

Answer (score 2):

Very helpful instructions.

Unfortunately I run into problems with `synclient` (`Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`) so I looked for an alternative script for AutoKey and found the [instructions in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/14882) very helpful. I just replaced the line starting with `os.system` with the following:

```
os.system("xinput --set-prop 'PS/2 Generic Mouse' 'Device Enabled' $(if [ $(expr `xinput --list-props 'PS/2 Generic Mouse' | grep 'Device Enabled' | cut -f2 -d :`) -eq 0 ]; then echo 1; else echo 0; fi)")
```

Answer (score 2):

**Touchpad scroll issue fixed**

I really appreciate  **"Dave Turvene"'s** great contribution for his driver and also thanks to **garyF** for his script.

It fixed by touchpad scroll issue on Dell inspiron 5720 running Ubuntu 12.04.

Few extra steps i did to make it work.

Here  are my steps to make the drivers and script run.

```
1) After you extract psmouse-alps-dst-0.4.tar to /usr/src (on command prompt go to /usr/src/psmouse-alps-dst-0.4).
2) `sudo chmod u+=rwx install.sh`   (give execute permission to install.sh)
3) `sudo gedit install.sh`
4) add    #!/bin/bash     (if using bash shell , which is the default shell)
5) `sudo ./install.sh`
[If you get some error. You might need to install dkms to make the script run]
[`sudo apt-get install dkms`].

6) the script will run and build the source.
7) after its completes you will get the message
"DKMS: install completed.
rmmod psmouse, wait=no
insmod /lib/modules/3.5.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/psmouse.ko 
MAIN: Done installing. Go to System Settings > Mouse and Touchpad to configure :-)"
8)In Ubuntu 12.04 click Dash Home in Launcher bar.
9) Then type mouse.
10) click the "Mouse and Toushpad" application.
11) click the "Touchpad" tab.
12) select "Two-finger scrolling".
13) close the application and you are all set.
```

Comment: thanks for adding the executable permission part... forgot to mention it :-) that can be overcome by using
`sudo bash install.sh`
but i didn't know that dkms needs to be installed. isn't it bundled with ubuntu install?

Answer (score 1):

I found a very useful driver made by Dave. I thank him cos I too have an N5110 and damn the Dell doesn't want to help

Here is the quick installation [link](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzNsvDx_ae6bQnFLQkNFT0dWc3c) to it.

You need to extract and copy the folder in `/usr/src/` and then run `install.sh` with root permission.

It's not complete but at least you will get edge scrolling, dual finger scrolling and be able to turn it off/on with <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>.