# How do I enable all touchpad features using the Alps driver on a Dell N5110?

Tags: touchpad, shortcut-keys

The touchpad is detected as PS/2 Generic Mouse. Installing [this](http://people.canonical.com/%7Esforshee/alps-touchpad/psmouse-alps-0.10/psmouse-alps-dkms_0.10_all.deb) driver doesn't help.

> After using it with this: "download that alps-dkms package and install
> it in /usr/src. from a terminal, navigate to
> /usr/src/psmouse-alps-0.10/src and then gedit alps.c in alps.c scroll
> down and copy the /* Dell Vostro 1400 */ line completely. In that line
> you will have to replace first 3 matches, that is , replace 0x73 ,
> 0x02 , 0x50 with 0x73 , 0x03 , 0x50 . Save the file and return to the
> terminal. In the terminal type dkms add -m psmouse -v alps-0.10 After
> this, type dkms build -m psmouse -v alps-0.10 after build is complete,
> install it with dkms install -m psmouse -v alps-0.10 after it installs
> it successfully, type rmmod psmouse && modprobe psmouse This will
> reload your psmouse module. Next, type xinput --list to see whether it
> loaded successfully or not. If it shows Alps/PS2 Alps GlidePoint in
> the xinput , than congrats. And i bet it will show as i got it working
> by this!

The touchpad is recognized as GlidePoint (which is wrong) and 2-finger scrolling isn't working. (I forgot to try to disable with Fn+F3, and now I installed Ubuntu again so I'll try to fix without any modified files)

How do I enable 2-finger scrolling, and add the option to enable/disable it with Fn+F3.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 64bit.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/141479/dell-inspiron-n5110-keyboard-touchpad

Comment: I have dell inspiron n5110 ..Ubuntu 13.04 clean installation ...every thing is working fine

Answer (score 0):

You really have two questions that you're asking. One is how to get Ubuntu to correctly recognize your touchpad, and the other is how to add the keybinding.

I don't know how to add the Fn+F3 keybinding to disable the touchpad. Is Fn+F3 a standard multimedia keystroke on your computer designed to disable the touchpad? If so, then you likely will not have to add any extra keybindings to get it to work once Ubuntu recognizes your touchpad correctly. Basically, Ubuntu likely correctly recognizes that you want to disable the touchpad, but, since it thinks that your touchpad is a mouse, sees no touchpads to disable.

One possible solution - upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04. The N5110's are fairly new computers, and as such, some of the hardware isn't necessarily supported by older kernel versions. I'm personally running Ubuntu 14.04 on a Dell Inspiron i3531, and that was initially very frustrating - only kernel version 3.13.0-32 and higher correctly supports the touchpad, and 14.04 came with version 3.13.0-25.

For what it is worth, Ubuntu 14.04 just had its first point release, so it's stable right out of the box with very few bugs. It's also not radically different than 12.04. And if your reason for not upgrading has to do with the commercialization, then install the unity tweak tool - you can get rid of all of the Unity web integration.