# Use windows touchpad driver in ubuntu

Tags: drivers, touchpad

Is it possible to use Windows touchpad driver in Ubuntu? I have a Dell n5110 and the touchpad is not recognized. I cannot use scroll, and most annoying, while typing the pointer usually jumps if the touchpad is touched. I see that there are lots of questions here and on the internet about this issue. Some claim to work, but I tried everything with no results.

Comment: @Fabby: It's quite an old question. I'm not sure what tagging it as duplicate or closing it will give you... If you take a look, the only meaningful answer, which gives the link to the alps touchpad driver appeared as an answer to that question and to mine, only after this question was posted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dell basically shipped a new touchpad from alps, where previous alps drivers don't work. it uses a new protocol to use the multi-finger touch pad. alps (or dell) doesn't care about giving the drivers to linux distros.

a team tried to reverse engineer the windows drivers to get it working in linux. and here's what they came up with...

1. [download tar file of touch pad driver for n5110 here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0BzNsvDx_ae6bQnFLQkNFT0dWc3c)
2. place the `psmouse-alps-dst-0.4` folder in `/usr/src` (u need root permission)
3. in terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), run #`sudo bash /usr/src/psmouse-alps-dst-0.4/install.sh`
4. configure touch pad in system settings :-)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use Windows drivers on Ubuntu unless it's for a network device under ndiswrapper, but maybe this link will help in getting your touchpad working properly:

[Dell Inspiron N5110 Keyboard & Touchpad](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141479/dell-inspiron-n5110-keyboard-touchpad)

Answer (score 0):

**No** , you cannot use Windows Driver for Ubuntu in any case . It is simple not possible. If you probably ask **How to make the DELL N5110 Touchpad working in Ubuntu** , you will probably get more proper help here.

Comment: There are plenty of questions regarding the Alps touchpad on Dell n5110 on the site, none which have a working answer.